Excel Chart - change where horizontal axis crosses Y-axis with openpyxl (Python)
I am looking for a way to use Python package openpyxl to change where my horizontal axis (x-axis) is located on my Excel chart along the y-axis. Currently, all my data is negative so the axis shows up at the top of the chart area. I would like to change where the horizontal axis crosses the Y-axis to a value of -9999 to force it to the bottom of the chart area. Thanks!
Sample code:
import random
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.chart import ScatterChart, Reference, Series

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
for r,val in enumerate([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]):
    ws.cell(row=r+1, column=1, value=val)
    ws.cell(row=r+1, column=2, value=-1*random.random()*val)

chart1 = ScatterChart()
xvalues1 = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=1, max_row=10)
yvalues1 = Reference(ws, min_col=2, min_row=1, max_row=10)
series1 = Series(values = yvalues1, xvalues = xvalues1)
chart1.series.append(series1)
ws.add_chart(chart1, "B11")
wb.save('test.xlsx')

Graph showing current behavior:

Settings I'd like to change with openpyxl:

Intended appearance of X-axis with chart:


You  can use chart1.x_axis.tickLblPos = "low" for forcing to change x-axis location. I have tested and worked. I hope it can help you
For change y-axis, you can use.
chart1.y_axis.crosses = "min"
chart1.y_axis.min = -9999  

So your final code will be
import random
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.chart import ScatterChart, Reference, Series

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active

for r, val in enumerate([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]):
    ws.cell(row=r+1, column=1, value=val)
    ws.cell(row=r+1, column=2, value=-1*random.random()*val)

chart1 = ScatterChart()
xvalues1 = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=1, max_row=10)
yvalues1 = Reference(ws, min_col=2, min_row=1, max_row=10)
series1 = Series(values=yvalues1, xvalues=xvalues1)
chart1.series.append(series1)

chart_location = "B11"
ws.add_chart(chart1, chart_location)

chart1.y_axis.crosses = "min"
chart1.y_axis.min = -9999  
chart1.x_axis.tickLblPos = "low"
wb.save('test.xlsx')

